# При запуске VS Code появляется окно с ошибкой создания файла в папке назначения.Отказано в доступе

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

[image: error]

Когда я запускаю VS Code(у меня Windows), каждый раз появляется это окно. На функционале IDE ошибка не отразилась существенно(ничего не заметил, все как обычно), но уже надоело. *Попробовать снова* не работает, просто перезапускается окно с ошибкой. *Пропускать файл* тоже не вариант, т.к. обновляется каждый раз окно, зато название файла каждый раз меняется(на картинке это unins000.exe, есть много других вариантов. Настолько, что их всех не пролистать). *Отменить установку* тоже не помогает, на некоторое кол-во времени пропадает, а потом заново(и при запуске).

Я уже и права админа пробовал, и просто спамил пропуск - никак.

Можно ли как-то скрыть это окно навсегда? Если да, то как?

Comment: Переустанавливать не пробовали?

Comment: Ну посмотрите на права этой директории - кто может писать, читать.

Comment: Вам вероятно нужно удалить VS Code, перезагрузиться и удалить папку `...\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\.` полностью. После чего запустить установку заново. Проблема в том, что папка создалась с правами другого пользователя и у вас нет к ней доступа. То есть теоретически вы сможете запустить VS Code без выскакивания ошибок, но только с правами Администратора. Второй вариант, открыть свойства папки `Microsoft VS Code` и выдать себе NTFS права на запись в нее.

Comment: с [правами](https://youtu.be/wABBWoBw_H4) на папку поразбираться попробовать или может быть сменить путь установки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1й способ: Переустановить vs code, чтобы он был установлен не только для пользователя, а для всей системы в `Program Files`. Как я понял у vs code два инсталлятора: один для системы, один для пользователей. Для системы можно взять здесь: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=win64.

2й способ: Вручную пойти по пути `C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` и выдать права на полный доступ для всех пользователей.